# IOS 10 force use 3G-4G instead WIFI

Tags: ios, objective-c, pjsip, 4g

I develope voip app with IOS 10 and pjsip library  and objective-C
I would like to use 3G-4G when signal WIFI isn't strong but i don't know how. Someone know if there is possibility to do ?
I read about Wifi-Assist , new iphone feature , but the official documentation tell that streaming app can't use this feature.
I've voip app. Can someone tell me if this is right ? Thanks

Comment: I;m sure you as a developer can't force this. This is all up to the user.

Comment: Considering this could cause the user to be charged without their knowledge, I pray this isn't possible without special permissions like on Android.